# Pass timeout to Foundation 6 loading

Tags: javascript, html, angular, timeout, zurb-foundation

I'm using Angular2 and Foundation 6 for creating a webapp.
I generate by myself scripts and styles from Foundation `.scss` files.

Here is my `index.html`

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>MyApp</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/foundation.min.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/foundation.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <my-app>Loading...</my-app>

        <script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/reflect-metadata/Reflect.js"></script>
        <script src="node_modules/systemjs/dist/system.src.js"></script>
        <script src="systemjs.config.js"></script>
        <script>
            System.import('app').catch(function(err) { console.error(err); });

            setTimeout(function () {
                $(document).foundation();
            }, 2000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

As you can see i had to add a timeout to correctly load some Foundation building blocks. If i remove that timeout Foundation doesn't work and then its classes don't work.

What is the right way to handle this kind of problem? Why i'm getting problem with Foundation loading?

Comment: i would try moving the jquery and foundation javascript includes to the body just before the other scripts.

Comment: I have already tried it, but it doesn't work.